# React JS trying to load CSS and JS file on HTTPs instead of HTTP

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I'm trying to load CSS and JS files from the app-assets folder in react js application, when I try to access the application on the internet the application is trying to access the CSS and JS on HTTPS instead of HTTP I'm running the application on HTTP.

How can I solve this, I don't want to host the application on HTTPS

[image]

[image]

Comment: Why would you not want your site to run on https? Certificates are free, get one and don't worry about this?

Comment: @cloned, my application is running on a Public IP Server, i don't have a domain for my public server

Comment: why this <link> doesnt have "/" on thye start of href?
you can also try remove cache or shift+f5 on this website